# How do you execute an 'x' file output from gcc on Windows?

Tags: gcc, mingw

I've downloaded a cosmology package from a university web site to a Windows machine.  I've also downloaded and installed mingw for the environment and compiler tools.  The makefile runs to completion without errors and produces a single file 'program.x'.

How do I execute this program on windows?

Comment: When it's a windows executable, you can change it's extension to".exe" and run it by double-clicking.

Comment: @nevilad  - That was it.  Many thanks.